# gray tiles when zooming into html

Tags: python, render, folium

I have the following script below:

```
import folium
import csv


def map_it():

    m = folium.Map(location=[-33.868820, 151.209290],tiles='Mapbox Bright', zoom_start=11)

    with open('rent_details.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        for line in csv_reader:
            lat = float(line['LATITUDE'])
            lng = float(line['LONGITUDE'])

            folium.Marker(location=[lat, lng], tooltip='click for more info').add_to(m)

    m.save(outfile='map.html')

map_it()
```

When I run the script, the marks get placed and I can see the map fine. However, once I zoom in, I get gray tiles. I found that zoom=11 works but zoom=12 does not render.

[working with zoom 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjeNv.jpg)

[not working with zoom 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4TuO.jpg)

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I opened the html file with firefox and safari but the issue persists

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75226705/is-there-a-way-to-make-folium-python-upscale-tiles-when-zooming-in-closer-than

Answer (score 0):

this is expected behaviour with tiles='Mapbox Bright'

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/699